# Algorithm to optimize space of 2D objects on 2D plane

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to write a tool to help figuring out how to cut 4x8 sheets of wood.  Basically I have some number of shapes of wood that I need to cut, with known sizes/dimensions as input, and then I want the program to figure out the optimal way to pack those shapes such that I use as few 4x8 sheets as possible.

I know this is just some algorithm out there, but I'm having problems figuring out what to google for and which one to choose.

The one 'hiccup' would be that there has to be a 1/8" border around every object, as that's the space taken up by the saw blade.

Comment: What sort of shapes?

Comment: Google for "bin packing" or "2d bin packing"

Comment: Squares, rectangles, and triangles of various sizes.

Comment: Triangles.. that makes it a lot harder actually. Do you want to allow arbitrary rotation as well?